# message not working in guildMemberAdd discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was trying to make a autorole event which gives the member role to a user when they join.
But I dont understand how to get the guild id if I can't get use the message.guild.id function in the guildMemberAdd event.I need it to get the memberRoleID property from the database.

This is my code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Guild = require('../database/models/guildSchema');

module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
    async execute(guildMember, message){
        //const guildMember = new GuildMember();
        let guildProfile = await Guild.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id});
        if(!guildProfile){
            guildProfile = await new Guild({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                guildID: message.guild.id
            });
            await guildProfile.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        const role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.get(guildProfile.memberRoleID);
        guildMember.roles.add(role.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `guildMemberAdd` event does not emit a `message` object. You can retrieve the guild from `guildMember.guild`, just like you did when defining `role`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Guild = require('../database/models/guildSchema');

module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
    async execute(guildMember){
        let guildProfile = await Guild.findOne({ guildID: guildMember.guild.id});
        if(!guildProfile){
            guildProfile = await new Guild({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                guildID: guildMember.guild.id
            });
            await guildProfile.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        const role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.get(guildProfile.memberRoleID);
        guildMember.roles.add(role.id);
    }
}
```

Documentation on [Client#guildMemberAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd)